# Vuex how to Access state data on component mounted or created hook?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex, quill

I'm trying to create a Quill.js editor instance once component is loaded using **mounted()** hook. However, I need to set the Quill's content using Quill.setContents() on the same *mounted()* hook with the data I received from **vuex.store.state** .

My trouble here is that the component returns empty value for the state data whenever I try to access it, irrespective of being on **mounted()** or **created()** hooks. I have tried with getters and computed properties too. Nothing seems to work.

I have included my **entry.js** file, concatenated all the components to make things simpler for you to help me.

```
Vue.component('test', {
    template: 
    `
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li v-for="note in this.$store.state.notes">
                    {{ note.title }}
                </li>
            </ul>
            {{ localnote }}
            <div id="testDiv"></div>
        </div>
    `,
    props: ['localnote'],
    data() {
        return {
            localScopeNote: this.localnote,
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.$store.dispatch('fetchNotes')
    },
    mounted() {
        // Dispatch action from store
        var quill = new Quill('#testDiv', {
            theme: 'snow'
        });
        // quill.setContents(JSON.parse(this.localnote.body));

    },
    methods: {
        setLocalCurrentNote(note) {
            console.log(note.title)
            return this.note = note;
        }
    }
});

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        message: "",
        notes: [],
        currentNote: {}
    },
    mutations: {
        setNotes(state,data) {
            state.notes = data;
            // state.currentNote = state.notes[1];
        },
        setCurrentNote(state,note) {
            state.currentNote = note;
        }
    },
    actions: {
        fetchNotes(context) {
            axios.get('http://localhost/centaur/public/api/notes?notebook_id=1')
                    .then( function(res) {
                        context.commit('setNotes', res.data);
                        context.commit('setCurrentNote', res.data[0]);
                    });
        }
    },
    getters: {
        getCurrentNote(state) {
            return state.currentNote;
        }
    }
});

const app = new Vue({
    store
}).$mount('#app');
```

And here is the index.html file where I'm rendering the component:

```
<div id="app">
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <test :localnote="$store.state.currentNote"></test>
</div>
```

Btw, I have tried the props option as last resort. However, it didn't help me in anyway. Sorry if this question is too long. Thank you for taking your time to read this. Have a nice day ;)

Comment: Try to use getter in v-for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied your code and tested it ( of-course I created my own dummy notes so I could remove the get request ) and I was able to get the notes display on a page.

A couple of things that I realized from your code, you may need to add a store property as there are places in your component ( test ) where you are referencing it, yet you only define it on the 'app' component. So in this section of your code modify as shown below:

```
props: ['localnote'],
    data() {
        return {
            localScopeNote: this.localnote,
            store : store
        }
    },
```

The key difference is the definition of the 'store' property. Please note that, what you have done, defining a "store" property in your app component, is correct, but the very same needs to be defined in "test" component as I have shown in the above code snippet above.

Second thing is, you are using $store and I guess that gives you undefined, unless as you said, in the libraries that you included this resolves accordingly, but on my side I had to remove all references of "$store" and replace it with just "store" (without the dollar sign).

Lastly for testing purposes, I would advise you to also

Comment: If you define 'vuex' in Vue instance like noted in the question, you can access this.$store inside components, don't need to define it again in every component.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I kept getting '$store' undefined errors, having copied the code as it is on the question.